# Thunderbird threaded view misses some replies

Tags: thunderbird

I'm corresponding with someone and their most recent reply (with the exact same subject line as the other emails) didn't get placed in the thread with the other emails. Specifically, there were two emails with the subject line:"RE: Bookclub", but the second one didn't make it in the thread. What's more, Gmail correctly grouped the emails as one conversation.

Anything I can do about this?

BTW, I have Thunderbird Conversations installed...not sure if that has any effect?